# Is there a open set such that $m(U_1-U_2)<\varepsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

If $U_1$ is a open set and has finite Lebesgue measure. Is there a open set $U_2\subset\subset U_1$ and the Lebesgue measure $m(U_1-U_2)< \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: What happens if from $U_1$ we delete a closed ball of measure $<\epsilon/2$?

Comment: @ajotatxe but $U_2\subset\subset U_1$ is not satisfied